# I have created a multi Zig Zag indicator in Pine Script , and can't figure out how to allow the user to toggle each Zig Zag line on/off

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have created a multi Zig Zag indicator, and can't figure out how to allow the user to toggle each Zig Zag line on/off.

Here is the code...

```
//@version=5
indicator('Multi Structure Zig Zag', max_lines_count=500)

length = input(100, title='Structure HTF')
h = ta.highest(high, length * 2 + 1)
l = ta.lowest(low, length * 2 + 1)
f_isMin(len) =>
    l == low[len]
f_isMax(len) =>
    h == high[len]

var dirUp = false
var lastLow = high * 100
var lastHigh = 0.0
var timeLow = bar_index
var timeHigh = bar_index
var line li = na
f_drawLine() =>
    _li_color = dirUp ? color.rgb(89, 42, 34, 6) : color.rgb(89, 42, 34, 6)
    line.new(timeHigh - length, lastHigh, timeLow - length, lastLow, xloc.bar_index, color =_li_color, width=2)




if dirUp
    if f_isMin(length) and low[length] < lastLow
        lastLow := low[length]
        timeLow := bar_index
        line.delete(li)
        li := f_drawLine()
        li

    if f_isMax(length) and high[length] > lastLow
        lastHigh := high[length]
        timeHigh := bar_index
        dirUp := false
        li := f_drawLine()
        li

if not dirUp
    if f_isMax(length) and high[length] > lastHigh
        lastHigh := high[length]
        timeHigh := bar_index
        line.delete(li)
        li := f_drawLine()
        li
    if f_isMin(length) and low[length] < lastHigh
        lastLow := low[length]
        timeLow := bar_index
        dirUp := true
        li := f_drawLine()
        if f_isMax(length) and high[length] > lastLow
            lastHigh := high[length]
            timeHigh := bar_index
            dirUp := false
            li := f_drawLine()
            li



//length 2
length2 = input(50, title='Structure MTF')
h2 = ta.highest(high, length2 * 2 + 1)
l2 = ta.lowest(low, length2 * 2 + 1)
f_isMin2(len2) =>
    l2 == low[len2]
f_isMax2(len2) =>
    h2 == high[len2]

var dirUp2 = false
var lastLow2 = high * 100
var lastHigh2 = 0.0
var timeLow2 = bar_index
var timeHigh2 = bar_index
var line li2 = na
f_drawLine2() =>
    _li_color2 = dirUp2 ? color.rgb(52, 8, 247) : color.rgb(52, 8, 247)
    line.new(timeHigh2 - length2, lastHigh2, timeLow2 - length2, lastLow2, xloc.bar_index, color=_li_color2, width=2, style=line.style_dashed)


if dirUp2
    if f_isMin2(length2) and low[length2] < lastLow2
        lastLow2 := low[length2]
        timeLow2 := bar_index
        line.delete(li2)
        li2 := f_drawLine2()
        li2

    if f_isMax2(length2) and high[length2] > lastLow2
        lastHigh2 := high[length2]
        timeHigh2 := bar_index
        dirUp2 := false
        li2 := f_drawLine2()
        li2

if not dirUp2
    if f_isMax2(length2) and high[length2] > lastHigh2
        lastHigh2 := high[length2]
        timeHigh2 := bar_index
        line.delete(li2)
        li2 := f_drawLine2()
        li2
    if f_isMin2(length2) and low[length2] < lastHigh2
        lastLow2 := low[length2]
        timeLow2 := bar_index
        dirUp2 := true
        li2 := f_drawLine2()
        if f_isMax2(length2) and high[length2] > lastLow2
            lastHigh2 := high[length2]
            timeHigh2 := bar_index
            dirUp2 := false
            li2 := f_drawLine2()
            li2

//length 3
length3 = input(10, title='Structure LTF')
h3 = ta.highest(high, length3 * 2 + 1)
l3 = ta.lowest(low, length3 * 2 + 1)
f_isMin3(len3) =>
    l3 == low[len3]
f_isMax3(len3) =>
    h3 == high[len3]

var dirUp3 = false
var lastLow3 = high * 100
var lastHigh3 = 0.0
var timeLow3 = bar_index
var timeHigh3 = bar_index
var line li3 = na
f_drawLine3() =>
    _li_color3 = dirUp3 ? color.rgb(166, 0, 255) : color.rgb(166, 0, 255)
    line.new(timeHigh3 - length3, lastHigh3, timeLow3 - length3, lastLow3, xloc.bar_index, color=_li_color3, width=2, style=line.style_dotted)

if dirUp3
    if f_isMin3(length3) and low[length3] < lastLow3
        lastLow3 := low[length3]
        timeLow3 := bar_index
        line.delete(li3)
        li3 := f_drawLine3()
        li3

    if f_isMax3(length3) and high[length3] > lastLow3
        lastHigh3 := high[length3]
        timeHigh3 := bar_index
        dirUp3 := false
        li3 := f_drawLine3()
        li3

if not dirUp3
    if f_isMax3(length3) and high[length3] > lastHigh3
        lastHigh3 := high[length3]
        timeHigh3 := bar_index
        line.delete(li3)
        li3 := f_drawLine3()
        li3
    if f_isMin3(length3) and low[length3] < lastHigh3
        lastLow3 := low[length3]
        timeLow3 := bar_index
        dirUp3 := true
        li3 := f_drawLine3()
        if f_isMax3(length3) and high[length3] > lastLow3
            lastHigh3 := high[length3]
            timeHigh3 := bar_index
            dirUp3 := false
            li3 := f_drawLine3()
            li3
```

I've tried everything I can think of but can't seem to come up with a solution. The only option is settings is "Lines" checked On or Off, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to separate them individually.

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean input. Something like that:

```
i_onLine1 = input.bool (true, "Line 1")
if dirUp and i_onLine1
    ...

if not dirUp and i_onLine1
    ...
```